# VisualStudio does not build a changed, referenced project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, solution

I've got two solutions, one containing a WinForms-Project and one containing a Utilities-Library.

To comfortably debug and develop the two projects I added the Utilities-Project to the WinForms-Project's Solution. Even though the Utilities-Project is still a seperate Project and should be kept seperate (also due the GIT Repos).

Now I've ran into the problem that changes I applied to the Utilities-Project do not affect the WinForms-Project because the Utilities do not seem to get rebuilt correctly.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and am referencing the Utilities-Project via Add reference->Project.

How should I restructure the projects/solutions? What might be the error?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your project build order.

Comment: Ordered correctly, checked twice

Comment: You have 1 solution with 2 projects, sitting on seperated folders, you edit the code in project B and build it. You make a reference to project B from your main project A. Does B builds ok ? you mention you get error - What is the error log in output ?

Comment: @SlapY: you may have some error in Utilities project whihc is failed to build. Try to build it (Utility) separately.

Comment: @ilansch thats right, (@Tigran too:) Utilities does not contain any erros so it builds okay - it just doesnt build together with Project A. Also, I'm expecting my Solution A to show me errors within Project A as well as Project B ?

Comment: If you build a *solution*, and your project dependencies are fine, both projects will be built. If you build only project A that exist inside the solution, why you expect project B to be built also ?

Comment: I expect the complete solution (or at least its changed projects) to be built when hitting F5/F6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the configuration manager to ensure that the project is set to build for the selected configuration and platform.

In the output window you will get a summary at the end.

```
========== Build: x succeeded, x failed, x up-to-date, x skipped ==========
```

If any projects are skipped then they are not set to build for that configuration/platform.

Also worth checking Visual Studio under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run as there are some options there that control when to build things. You can also turn the build output up/down which may give some clues as to why it is not building.

Comment: I've got 1 built, 0 failed, 2 skipped (Probably Utilities and the Setup) when pressing F6

Comment: Skipped means that it is not set to build for that configuration. Check the configuration manager again for all configurations and platforms.

Comment: Thanks Lee Willis, I just found that out by myself. That was it.